# No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my code and string values contains the passed data, "temp" contains the no of data which is stored in the string array. The data is then stored in a `sqlparameter` object and then passed as an object in `SqlQuery`:

```
    public List<T> updateSiteDetails<T>(int SiteId, int CategoryId, string[] values)
    {
        int temp = values.Count()+1;
        int Counter = 0;


        SqlParameter[] sParams = new SqlParameter[temp]; // Parameter count
        sParams[0] = new SqlParameter();
        sParams[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        sParams[0].ParameterName = "@SiteId";
        sParams[0].Value = SiteId;

        sParams[1] = new SqlParameter();
        sParams[1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        sParams[1].ParameterName = "@CategoryId";
        sParams[1].Value = CategoryId;

        for (int i = 2,j=1; i < temp;i++,j++)
        {
            sParams[i] = new SqlParameter();
            sParams[i].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            sParams[i].ParameterName = "@value"+j;
            sParams[i].Value = values[j];
        }
        object[] parameters=new object[]{sParams};

        List<T> SiteDetails = null;
        using (SBDEntities db = new SBDEntities())
        {
            SiteDetails = db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("Sp_Update_AppData", parameters).ToList();//error is here
            return SiteDetails;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parameters must be added to a SQL Command and the Parameters must be the same as in the commands CommandText.  I cannot tell from the posted code where the error is occurring.

Comment: SiteDetails = db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("Sp_Update_AppData", parameters).ToList();//error is here
            return SiteDetails; error is here, i am not using any sqlCommand

Comment: A query is attached to a command which is the root problem with the error.

Comment: if i directy do like this :-   SiteDetails = db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("Sp_Update_SpearAppData @SiteId,@CategoryId,@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4",
                   new Object[] { new SqlParameter("@SiteId", SiteId), new SqlParameter("@CategoryId", CategoryId), new SqlParameter("@value1",values[1]),new SqlParameter("@value2",values[2]),
                      new SqlParameter("@value3",values[3]),new SqlParameter("@value4",values[4])}).ToList();
                return SiteDetails;    it works